# How do you create an audience in Firebase to filter events by User ID

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm using Analytics.logEvent(myEventName, userInfo) to log a custom event and I'd like to be able to search the Firebase console to see if the event happens for a particular user.

Prior to the event the code is calling Analytics.setUserId(someIdentifier), and additionally I pass the identifier within a dictionary and this is passed as the userInfo parameter to logEvent().

I couldn't find anyway of searching for events that occur for a user id, but came across this past question [Firebase Analytics Filter By User ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137190/firebase-analytics-filter-by-user-id).

The answer there says to create an audience, however I've read the instructions on how to create an audience but am still not seeing any way of being able to search via a user id.
Some of the comments to the answer say to use setUserProperty() rather than setUserId(). S0 I added both to my code, but am not able to find anyway within the Firebase console/the audience to search using user id.

Has anybody done something similar to this can can comment, preferably with details, how to do it, specifically how to set up the audience if this is the only means.

(I ran the code yesterday, then allowed 24 hours for the events to display in the console)

Comment: Did you figure this out?