# How do I filter firebase app analytics data by user?

Tags: android, firebase, analytics

I am trying to test my app by conducting a small study with 4 users. Hence, I am trying to gather analytics and the events I have defined and filter them by the user specifically.

I know that there exists a method to set user IDs and make user properties in Firebase, however, all user-specific properties by which you can filter the reports are thresholded by Google (Essentially they won't let you see filtered data that might let you infer a users' sensitive data unless there are more than 10 users for that filter). Is there any way I can see user-specific analytics and events using Firebase? If not can you refer to some analytics tools meant for small studies such as the one I am trying to conduct?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to filter on a specific user ID in the Analytics console in Firebase or in Google Analytics' own console.

To make us of this user ID, you will have to [export the Analytics data to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics#integrations_with_other_services) and filter there, or by creating an audience on the user ID as explained in the answer to this question: [Firebase Analytics Filter By User ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137190/firebase-analytics-filter-by-user-id).